# how to cronjob perform in CI.. to call the particular controller in automatically call those send the email

Tags: codeigniter, cron

Actually I want to perform the cron job  those particular time of session call automatically send the email also I'm calling the controller  particular in CI but it unable to perform the cron job.?

error :

> /home/a7ndzp5tm2vd/public_html/projects/PolicyManager/insurancecompany/application/controllers/Sendsms_email.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
>   /home/a7ndzp5tm2vd/public_html/projects/PolicyManager/insurancecompany/application/controllers/Sendsms_email.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'BASEPATH'`
>   /home/a7ndzp5tm2vd/public_html/projects/PolicyManager/insurancecompany/application/controllers/Sendsms_email.php: line 3: `if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`

```php
<?php

  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class Sendsms_email extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->model('Product');
         $this->load->model('queries');
         $this->load->model('User_model');
         $this->load->library('input');
     }


     public function index() { 
         $this->load->library('email');

         if($this->input->is_cli_request())
         { 
         @$r1 = $this->user_model->smsten();
         //print_r($r1);
         if ($r1 != '') {

             foreach ($r1 as $key => $users):

                 $encryption_key = 1234567812345678;
                 $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) .                      chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);

                 $cn = $users['contactno'];
                 $cn1 = $cn . ':' . $iv;
                 $econtactnol = explode(':', $cn1);
                 $dcontactnol = openssl_decrypt($econtactnol[0], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, $econtactnol[1]);

                 $cname = $users['name'];
                 $cname1 = $cname . ':' . $iv;
                 $ename1 = explode(':', $cname1);
                 $dname1 = openssl_decrypt($ename1[0], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, $ename1[1]);

                 $emailid = $users['email'];
                 $emailid1 = $emailid . ':' . $iv;
                 $eemailid = explode(':', $emailid1);
                 $demail = openssl_decrypt($eemailid[0], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0, $eemailid[1]);

                 $p_vehicle= $users['vechicle_no'];
                   $p1_vehicle = $p_vehicle . ':' . $iv;
                   $v_vehicle[] = explode(",", $p_vehicle);

                   //print_r($v_vehicle);
                 foreach ($v_vehicle as $k_vehicle => $v1_vehicle) {
                     foreach ($v1_vehicle as $k1_vehicle => $k2_vehicle) {
                         $ss_vehicle[] = $k2_vehicle . ":";
                     }
                 }
                 $count_v_vehicle=  count($ss_vehicle);
                 for ($i = 0; $i < $count_v_vehicle; $i++) {

                     $dvehicleno = openssl_decrypt($ss_vehicle[$i], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0);

                      $table_vehicle_value[] = $dvehicleno ;
                 }

                 $p = $users['GROUP_CONCAT(p.policyno)'];
                 $p1 = $p . ':' . $iv;

                // $epolicydetail = explode(':', $p1);
                 //print_r($p);
                 $v[] = explode(",", $p);

                 foreach ($v as $k => $v1) {
                     foreach ($v1 as $k1 => $k2) {
                         $ss[] = $k2 . ":";
                     }
                 }
                 $count_v = count($ss);
                 for ($i = 0; $i < $count_v; $i++) {

                     $dpolicydetail = openssl_decrypt($ss[$i], AES_256_CBC, $encryption_key, 0);


                     $shw2[] = $dpolicydetail . ",";
                      $table_poilcy_value[] = $dpolicydetail ;
                 }
                 $sa = rtrim(join($shw2), ',');
                 $count_policy= count($table_poilcy_value);
                 echo"\n"; //                echo $dcontactnol;
                 $contactno = $dcontactnol; /* Separate mobile no with commas */

                 $message = "Your policy $sa will be expired in 10 days.";
                // print_r($message);

                $senderId = "DEMOOS"; /* Sender ID */
                $serverUrl = "msg.msgclub.net";
                $authKey = "14f5d3ca75bc4de1761d4af9e7d83d38"; /* Authentication key (get from sms service provider) */
                $route = "1";
                $this->sendsmsGET($contactno, $senderId, $route, $message, $serverUrl, $authKey);


                 $output='<h3>'.$message.'</h3>';
                 $output .= '<table style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;

                border-collapse: collapse;">';
                 $output .= '<tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <td style="text-align:center; border: 1px solid  black; border-collapse: collapse;" colspan="3">Policy Reminder</td>
                    </tr>';
                 $output .= '
                      <tr>

                      <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;">
                     <td style="width:30%;  border: 1px solid black;
                     border-collapse: collapse;">Policy No</td>
                     <td style="width:50%;border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse">Vehicle No.</td>

                     </tr>';

                       for ($record=0;$record<$count_policy;$record++)
                 {
                      $output .= '  <tr style="width:100%;  border: 1px solid black;
                      border-collapse: collapse;" >
                      <td style="  border: 1px solid black;
                      border-collapse:  collapse;">' . $table_poilcy_value[$record] . '</td>
                     <td style="  border: 1px solid black;
                      border-collapse:  collapse;">'.$table_vehicle_value[$record].'</td>
                     </tr>
                      ';
                }

                 $output .= '</table>'; //                print_r($output);
                 $to_email = "xyz@gmail.com";

                 $from_email = "xyz@gmail.com";

                 $subject = "reminder for policy";

                        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
                     $this->email->initialize($config);
                 $this->email->from($from_email);
                 $this->email->to($to_email);
                 $this->email->subject($subject);
                 $this->email->message($output);

                 //Send mail

                 if($this->email->send())
                 { //                     echo "succesfully";
                 }

                 unset($v_vehicle);
                 unset($v);
                 unset($ss_vehicle);
                 unset($ss);
                 unset($dcontactnol);
                 unset($shw2);
                 unset($table_poilcy_value);

             endforeach;
         }  }

      }

 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you run the same URL you are using in the CRON in a browser? All a CRON job does is execute a URL (in this case) every so often as you have defined. what is your cron command?

Comment: user interface  thround run the cron job..

Comment: still error show permission diened

Comment: What is your Cron Job command line?

Comment: <a7ndzp5tm2vd@p3plcpnl0714> /usr/local/bin/php /home/a7ndzp5tm2vd/public_html/projects/PolicyManager/insurancecompany/application/views/cron_jobView.php

Comment: not show the data those fetch by query in file .. so pls tell what to do?<a7ndzp5tm2vd@p3plcpnl0714> /usr/local/bin/php /home/a7ndzp5tm2vd/public_html/projects/PolicyManager/insurancecompany/application/views/cron_jobView.php this commanad run

Comment: Did the answer below suit your needs? Could you mark it as accepted if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing exactly HOW you're trying to run the cron, but this is how you should:

```
* * * * * php /home/path/to/main/codeigniter/index.php controller_name method_name "parameter"
```

Parameter is optional.
Replace the `* * * * *` with your desired schedule and the path for your actual path. For instance, the site I'm working on today lives on `/home/webuser/public/www/` so if I wanted to run something (a method called hourly housekeeping) on my dedicated cron controller (conveniently called "Cron") every hour on the hour I'd do:

```
00 * * * * php /home/webuser/public/www/index.php cron hourly_housekeeping
```

As a safeguard, you should run cron tasks on a dedicated controller which cannot be accesed through a browser. You can use Codeigniter's `is_cli()` to make sure the execution is being initiated through the CLI and refuse to run otherwise. 
For that purpose, you may have something like this in your controller construct:

```
if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) show_error('Here be dragons. No browsers served here');
```

Hope you can get it to work